# Comparing two text files printing result in new header

Tags: perl, awk, ksh

Okay i will reupdate this

I have 2 files - File1.txt , File2.txt

File1 is base template

File2 is having status result

#### file1.txt

```
N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6
XX,ZZ,XC,EE,RR,BB
XC,CF,FG,RG,GH,GH
```

#### file2.txt

```
DF,GH,MH,FR,FG,GH,NA
XX,ZZ,XC,EE,RR,BB,OK
```

Below command compares column 1 in both files if it matches then it retrieves the value from 7th cell in file2 and appends in file1.txt as last column with new header.

if not found NA is updated .

Command used :

```
awk -F  '
  FNR==NR { a[$1]=$7; next }
  FNR==1  { print $0; len=length($0); next }
  {
    printf $0
    cont=(($1 in a) ? ","a[$1] : ",NA")
    for ( i=length($0)+1; i<=len-length(cont); i++)
      printf " " 
    print cont
  }
'  file2.txt file1.txt > tmp &&
```

Day1 - After running above command

```
N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,D1
XX,ZZ,XC,EE,RR,BB,OK
XC,CF,FG,RG,GH,GH,NA
```

Day 2 - After running above command

```
N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,D1,D2
XX,ZZ,XC,EE,RR,BB,OK,OK
XC,CF,FG,RG,GH,GH,NA,NA
```

At Day3 i inserted a new row in File1 at bottom

```
N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,D1,D2
XX,ZZ,XC,EE,RR,BB,OK,OK
XC,CF,FG,RG,GH,GH,NA,NA
DM,LC,VF,GR,GH,ES
```

now when i run above command on Day3 , i need output like this

```
N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,D1,D2,D3
XX,ZZ,XC,EE,RR,BB,OK,OK,OK
XC,CF,FG,RG,GH,GH,NA,NA,NA
DM,LC,VF,GR,GH,ES,,,NA
```

Comment: This question should indeed refer to the other, but it should also be sufficiently self-contained to be answerable on its own — and it currently is not. You show an example row with 6 input fields; will there ever be more, or fewer, fields in the input? Are all the missing fields to be treated as empty, except for the 16th which should be inserted as NA? The first line is the header, presumably. Does the header line appear in both files, or just the main file? Does the code need to check whether the data in the second file already exists in the first file, or does it simply add rows?

Comment: Your description of '10th day' and '10th time' is completely unclear to someone who doesn't know what you're doing. It isn't clear if you have a single file, `file2.txt`, that contains repeated information about the OK or NA status of a day's results, or whether you have 10 files. It isn't clear how the XC line gets a bunch on NA values tagged onto it; it doesn't appear at all in `file2.txt`. It isn't clear whether you have 10 'day' columns from the start, or whether you add the D1 column on the first run, the D2 column on the second, and so on. All in all, you've not yet explained yourself.

Comment: That is much clearer now — thank you.  Remember that we don't know all the context you have, but we need to know enough to understand the issues causing you trouble.  I observe that you would save yourself a lot of angst if you insisted that the process that adds a new record provides the appropriate number of commas and NA or OK entries.  I'm also a little puzzled about how you ever get something to change its status after it is added; it would seem that the program you're seeking can't do that.

Comment: is that not possible in awk to identify the empty cells in each line and column and replace with comma instead ?

Comment: got it

 sed -e 's/  \s/,/g' file1.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` script seems to do the job:

```
awk -F, '
BEGIN   { OFS = FS }
FNR==NR { a[$1] = $7; next }
FNR==1  { n1 = n = NF + 1; $n = "D" (n-6); print; next }
        { $n1 = ($1 in a) ? a[$1] : "NA"; print }
' file2.txt file1.txt
```

OFS is the output field separator; FS is the (input) field separator.  Both are set to `,`, FS by the `-F` option and OFS by the assignment.  This makes it easy to get the correct number of fields in the output.  `awk`'s string concatenation with no operator, exemplified by `"D" (n-6)` is slightly weird; you get used to it, up to a point, but it still looks a little odd.

#### Example

The example run uses a program `ow` that has the synopsis:

```
ow file cmd …args…
```

It preserves the contents of the file by having the `cmd …args…` write to a temporary file, and if the command succeeds (exit status 0) and the output is not empty, it then preserves a copy of the original, ignores a number of signals, and then copies the temporary output over the original and cleans up.  It is rather useful — code at the bottom.  This is how I did my test.  Clearly, I could use `tmp=$(mktemp tmp.XXXXXX); awk … file1.txt > $tmp; mv $tmp file1.txt` instead, or something along those lines.  However, since I have `ow`, I use it.

```
$ cat file1.txt
N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6
XX,ZZ,XC,EE,RR,BB
XC,CF,FG,RG,GH,GH
$ ow file1.txt awk -F, '
> BEGIN   { OFS = FS }
> FNR==NR { a[$1] = $7; next }
> FNR==1  { n1 = n = NF + 1; $n = "D" (n-6); print; next }
>         { $n1 = ($1 in a) ? a[$1] : "NA"; print }
> ' file2.txt file1.txt
$ cat file1.txt
N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,D1
XX,ZZ,XC,EE,RR,BB,OK
XC,CF,FG,RG,GH,GH,NA
$ ow file1.txt awk -F, '
> BEGIN   { OFS = FS }
> FNR==NR { a[$1] = $7; next }
> FNR==1  { n1 = n = NF + 1; $n = "D" (n-6); print; next }
>         { $n1 = ($1 in a) ? a[$1] : "NA"; print }
> ' file2.txt file1.txt
$ cat file1.txt
N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,D1,D2
XX,ZZ,XC,EE,RR,BB,OK,OK
XC,CF,FG,RG,GH,GH,NA,NA
$ echo DM,LC,VF,GR,GH,ES >> file1.txt
$ ow file1.txt awk -F, '
> BEGIN   { OFS = FS }
> FNR==NR { a[$1] = $7; next }
> FNR==1  { n1 = n = NF + 1; $n = "D" (n-6); print; next }
>         { $n1 = ($1 in a) ? a[$1] : "NA"; print }
> ' file2.txt file1.txt
$ cat file1.txt
N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,D1,D2,D3
XX,ZZ,XC,EE,RR,BB,OK,OK,OK
XC,CF,FG,RG,GH,GH,NA,NA,NA
DM,LC,VF,GR,GH,ES,,,NA
$
```

Note that as you assign to `$i` and `i` is larger than NF was, NF increases, and any missing fields are created as empty fields.

The first working version of this script had more complex logic, with a loop creating the empty fields, but since `awk` will do that automatically, the script simplified considerably.  You'll often find that with a bit of time and care, initial solutions can be simplified and cleaned up.

However, it is probably also relevant to point out that this code is very trusting.  It doesn't ensure that there are exactly 7 fields in `file2.txt`.  It doesn't check that each line in `file1.txt` has either the same number of fields as the first line in the file or exactly 6 fields.  If you supply screwy data in, you get screwy data out — the age-old [GIGO](http://acronymfinder.com/GIGO.html) principle: [Garbage In, Garbage Out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

#### `ow`

```
:   "@(#)$Id: ow.sh,v 1.6 2005/06/30 18:14:08 jleffler Exp $"
#
#   Overwrite file
#   From: The UNIX Programming Environment by Kernighan and Pike
#   Amended: remove PATH setting; handle file names with blanks.

case $# in
0|1)    echo "Usage: $0 file command [arguments]" 1>&2
    exit 1;;
esac

file="$1"
shift
new=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/ovrwr.$$.1
old=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/ovrwr.$$.2

trap "rm -f '$new' '$old' ; exit 1" 0 1 2 15

if "$@" >"$new"
then
    cp "$file" "$old"
    trap "" 1 2 15
    cp "$new" "$file"
    rm -f "$new" "$old"
    trap 0
    exit 0
else
    echo "$0: $1 failed - $file unchanged" 1>&2
    rm -f "$new" "$old"
    trap 0
    exit 1
fi
```

---

#### Adding date instead of Dn to heading

> Is it possible that `awk` can print a date in the header instead of *D1*?

If you want the current date added, you have two main options. One, using GNU gawk (often also installed as awk), then the [time functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions) make it easy. Failing that, `awk -v date=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d') -F, …` has the system command date format a value and pass it into the awk script as variable date, which you can then print where you want it.  If you want arbitrary dates passed in, then the second mechanism is the one to use.

```
awk -F, -v date=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d') '
BEGIN   { OFS = FS }
FNR==NR { a[$1] = $7; next }
FNR==1  { n1 = n = NF + 1; $n = date; print; next }
        { $n1 = ($1 in a) ? a[$1] : "NA"; print }
' file2.txt file1.txt
```

That forces today's date into the command.  You can also do things prospectively or retrospectively, such as:

```
tmp=$(mktemp coladd.XXXXXXXXX)
trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

for dd in $(seq 1 31)
do
    awk -F, -v date="2014-12-$dd" '
    BEGIN   { OFS = FS }
    FNR==NR { a[$1] = $7; next }
    FNR==1  { n1 = n = NF + 1; $n = date; print; next }
            { $n1 = ($1 in a) ? a[$1] : "NA"; print }
    ' file2.txt file1.txt > $tmp
    mv $tmp file1.txt
done
```

Given this extra flexibility, I'd recommend using the externally-defined date over GNU's internal date manipulating functions, but [YMMV](http://www.acronymfinder.com/YMMV.html).

Comment: how to insert date in header for above code 
awk -v date=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d') -F